# How to Handle HTTP 302 Redirects in MS Flow

Tags: power-automate

I'm trying to use MS Flow to extract data from an existing website. To do this I must make two requests:

1. A request to a login form
2. A request to retrieve some data

When I fire a HTTP connector to the login form the site responds with a HTTP 302 redirect. This is expected. The Flow fails on receiving the HTTP 302 response and does not proceed to the second request. How can I receive a 302 response and not have my Flow halt with an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that works for me is to set the "Configure run after" property of the **following action** to include "has failed".

Comment: please can you put up a screen shot of your solution!

Answer (score 2):

I was on the same situation, and thanks to the OP, that solution was the way to go.

If anyone with the same problem, at the end are some screeshots to help (sorry, the UI is in french).

This is how i solved it:

1. Add a condition after the 'HTTP' request, to catch the 302 response statut code.
2. Configure the 'Execute After' of this condition block by clicking on its menu.
   (the three dots on the top right of this block)
   [image: Show the Run After Property]
3. Enable 'Has Failed' option to be considered as a trigger for this block (the condition block), and validate that.
   [image: Configure the Run After Property]

So, this will allow the flow to continue even if the HTTP request will fail.

Comment: Thank you! This solution solved my issue and the screenshots made it much easier (thanks for putting the effort of translating them to English)